# Is there any sollution or code to find wsdl all methods and which type this methods GET or POST etc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl : https://www.lb.lt/webservices/ExchangeRates/ExchangeRates.asmx?WSDL

I want to extract all methods and defined types of methods GET,POST etc.

Is there any way that I can do this in .NET Core

Comment: In Visual Studio?

Comment: For Example I have a wsdl as posted above it has 4 methos GetUSDEURO,GetUSDCAD etc
and I want to show them on UI and show their body and response

Comment: This looks like an [X/Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In .Net the tool of choice to parse WSDLs and turn them into code has mostly been [Svcutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe).

Not sure which version this is, but [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/tree/main/src/dotnet-svcutil) you can find the source code of the project. You could study it and see where it parses the WSDL structure to get the data you are after.

And there is also the option to parse the WSDL as XML (using a DOM, XSLT, etc.) and go for the elements that you want, knowing the structure of a WSDL file is standard and defined by various specifications.